# Why the value in Map of STL is not changing?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

**I am subtracting the value in map(Key-Value pair) by 1 if the value is grater than 1**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     // Creating a map with 4 element
    map<int,int> m;
    m[1]=1;
    m[2]=2;
    m[3]=1;
    m[4]=3;
     //Printing the output
    for(auto x: m)cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<endl;
    //Applying substraction
    for(auto x: m)
    {
        if(x.second>1)
        {
            x.second--;
        }
    }
    cout<<"After subtraction operation: \n";
    for(auto x: m)cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<endl;

}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Change `for(auto x: m)` to `for(auto &x: m)`  It's making a copy and you are then you are changing the value of copy not the original.

Comment: @RichardCritten Post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 5):

`auto` uses the same rules for type deduction as templates do, and they favour value types, not reference types.  So:

```
for (auto x : m)
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (std::map<int,int>::value_type x : m)
```

and this makes a copy of the key and the value.  You then modify the copy, and nothing in the actual map is changed.  What you need is:

```
for (auto& x : m)
```

(or, if you are really masochistic):

```
for (std::map<int,int>::value_type& x : m)
```

Comment: for middling amounts of masochism, `for (std::map<int, int>::reference x : m)`